# PHP: setcookie() to expire after the year 2038

Tags: php, cookies, unix-timestamp, year2038

Currently I'm converting all my PHP unix timestamps to work beyond [2k38 issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

I noticed that [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) **expire date** parameter uses the unix timestamp. Is there a way to set expire date with alternative method, maybe using the DateTime class somehow?

From the PHP document about expire date:

> Note: You may notice the expire parameter takes on a Unix timestamp,
>   as opposed to the date format Wdy, DD-Mon-YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT, this is
>   because PHP does this conversion internally.

Comment: I don't think so. The question is it is really **now** an issue for you? 2038 is in 18 years. I am 100% convinced your software will be _rewritten and adapted_ til this date...

Comment: What is wrong with `setcookie` taking a Unix timestamp? There is nothing that inherently limits them to only go up to the year 2038. If you have 64 bit PHP I would expect setting a cookie expiry beyond 2038 would be fine.

Comment: You can re implement the `setcookie` function using the `header` to set them by your self - but I think that you don't understand correctly the problem: after the year 2038 we still can use unix timestamp..

Comment: In fact I've just tested it and set a cookie to expire in 2060 without any issue.

Comment: @AlBundy I'm asking this question because I'm currently rewriting my software

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot change the function signature. Well, not at least without fiddling with strange PHP extensions. But since the [cookie spec](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc6265.html) does not use Unix timestamps at all you can simply write your own function and call `header()` manually:

```
Set-Cookie: lang=en-US; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2099 10:18:14 GMT
Set-Cookie: lang=en-US; Max-Age=8640000
```

... and hope that browsers are able to process the date:

> If the expiry-time is later than the last date the user agent can
>      represent, the user agent MAY replace the expiry-time with the last
>      representable date.

Or you can simply use `seecookie()` anyway. As far as I know, it'll only be an issue in some 32-bit versions of PHP.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for. Thank you.